# Regex or Functions for validating a file?

Tags: java, regex

I have a task on my hand to validate the schema of a text file which holds the following data

50 entries in the following format,

Serial numbers are from 1-50 followed by a tab followed by a random number n ranging from 100<=n<=500

```
e.g. 1 <tab> 256
```

Since a regular expression is easier to check the schema of the file and is more maintainable I am preferring to use regex rather than a class which will parse each string and validate within no time

The output file should be like

```
Line 1 formatted correctly
Invalid format on line 2 (51 1000) + (Error message that can be set using a custom exception class)
```

My question is, can regex be powerful enough to give me the desired output i.e raise an exception to set in the correct way?

My try is below

```
public class TestOutput {

    private final int MAX_LINES_TO_READ = 50;

    private final String REGEX = "RAWREGEX";

    public void testFile(String fileName) {

        int lineCounter = 1;

        try {

            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fileName));

            String line = br.readLine();

            while ((line != null) && (lineCounter <= MAX_LINES_TO_READ)) {

                // Validate the line is formatted correctly based on regular expressions                
                if (line.matches(REGEX)) {
                    System.out.println("Line " + lineCounter + " formatted correctly");
                }
                else {
                    System.out.println("Invalid format on line " + lineCounter + " (" + line + ")");
                }

                line = br.readLine();
                lineCounter++;
            }

            br.close();

        } catch (Exception ex) {
            System.out.println("Exception occurred: " + ex.toString());
        }
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {

        TestOutput vtf = new TestOutput();

        vtf.testFile("transactions.txt");
    }   
}
```

Here are my questions

1. How the optimal design should look like (use regex or not)?
2. If yes, What regex to use?

Comment: For just 50 entries performance is not relevant. Every approach will finish fast enough.

Comment: It seems that implementing [numeric ranges](https://www.regular-expressions.info/numericranges.html) with RegEx will be more complicated than straight forward JS validation.

Comment: Must the serial numbers be in order? ie does line n start with serial number n?

Comment: Great point! The serial number may not be in order! And any serial number greater than 50 or less than 1 should be invalid @Bohemian

Comment: @anubhava `^` and `$` are unnecessary when used with `String#matches()`; they are implied.

Comment: @anubhava fair enough, I just like to remind people of ways to reduce code where possible, and regex being hard to read can do with as many reductions as you can find IMHO.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this regex:

```
String REGEX = "([1-9]|[1-4]\\d|50)\t([1-4]\\d\\d|500)";
```

See [live demo](https://rubular.com/r/d8THA9EqJMWypQ).

To explain...

`[1-9]|[1-4]\\d|50` means “any number 1-50”, achieved by three alternations 1-9, 10-49 and 50.

Similarly, `[1-4]\\d\\d|500` means “100-500”, achieved by two alternations 100-499 and 500.

With only 50 lines, “performance” is irrelevant (unless you’re doing it 100’s of times per second) - pick the approach that is most readable and understandable. If you can use regex, it usually results in less code, and it performs well enough.

---

Test code:

```
private final String REGEX = "([1-9]|[1-4]\\d|50)\\t([1-4]\\d\\d|500)";

public void testFile(String fileName) {
    int lineCounter = 1;
    try {
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fileName));
        String line = br.readLine();
        while ((line != null) && (lineCounter <= MAX_LINES_TO_READ)) {
            if (line.matches(REGEX)) {
                System.out.println("Line " + lineCounter + " formatted correctly");
            } else {
                System.out.println("Invalid format on line " + lineCounter + " (" + line + ")");
            }
            line = br.readLine();
            lineCounter++;
        }
        br.close();
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        System.out.println("Exception occurred: " + ex.toString());
    }
}
```

Test file:

```
1   123
50  346
23  145
68  455
1   535
```

Output:

```
Line 1 formatted correctly
Line 2 formatted correctly
Line 3 formatted correctly
Invalid format on line 4 (68    455)
Invalid format on line 5 (1 535)
```

Comment: Tested the above regex, fails

Comment: @liger what does it fail on?

Comment: Used regex101 to test this on following inputs {50 346},
{23 145},
{68 455},
{1 535} Fails for all of them

Comment: @liger did you replace the double backslashes with single backslashes when you used regex101? Double backslashes are needed in java to code a literal backslash - the actual regex would be `([1-9]|[1-4]\d|50)\t([1-4]\d\d|500)`

Comment: @Liger I’ve added a link to a live demo that shows this regex working with all of the examples you listed in your comment.

Comment: Yes made that correction realized it late but with a double backslash in java, it still does not match. Used a similar code as posted in question and replaced with your regex. I have to make some more check for this regex to work with "matches"

Comment: @liger The linked demo shows it working correctly for all of your examples. For which case does it not work?

Comment: It failed to match any of the examples mentioned in your example in java. I guess it's the subgroups, maybe something else with the implementation of matches

Comment: @Liger My regex passes every example you have provided. I have pasted in your code, but with my regex, shown the contents of the file and the output it produced (which was correct). I'm very curious to known why you believe my regex "doesn't work". If run you my code, does it work? Could it be that there is white space at the start, end or within of your lines?

Comment: I spent almost 2 hours debugging why the regex was not working! Guess what! The input file had extra characters somehow! Which brings me to another question! How can I find why the matches function fails! I'll post this in another thread. Thanks!

Comment: @liger you can’t get info about why a pattern matched or didn’t match. You must resort to debugging, perhaps printing the hex value of each non-printable character and its position in the line for every non-matching line. Rather than meet the problem head on, You could clean bad characters from input, eg `line = line.replaceAll("^[0-9\t]", "");`, which is what I would do. It makes the problem less brittle to unimportant extra characters and thus friendlier to users.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an implementation using a Regex. The matcher provides the sub-expressions for each match. And the limitations are implemented in Java.

```
boolean matchLine(String line) {
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("^(\\d+)\\t(\\d+)");
    boolean ok = false;
    try {
        Matcher m = p.matcher(line);
        int i = Integer.parseInt(m.group(1));
        int n = Integer.parseInt(m.group(2));
        ok = 1 <= i && i <= MAX_LINES_TO_READ && 100<=n && n<=500;
    } catch(NumberFormatException e){};

    return ok;
}
```

Comment: Fixed the `\\t`

Answer (score 0):

Just a quick implementation below. Note that for such a trivial problem speed is not an issue. As noted in the comments, writing a regular expression for numeric ranges is probably harder than just splitting each line on the tab, parsing the integers from the string parts, and checking the proper ranges using good old `if`.

```java
public class SplitByTab {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String input = "1   123\n" + "2 456\n" + "3 789\n" + "4 234\n" + "5 345\n" + "6 890";

        for (String line : input.split("\\r?\\n")) {
            validateLine(line);
        }
    }

    private static void validateLine(String line) {
        String[] parts = line.split("\\t");
        if (parts.length != 2) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(String.format("line '%s' does not contain exactly one tab", line));
        }
        try {
            Integer serial = Integer.valueOf(parts[0]);
            if (serial < 0 || serial > 50) {
                throw new IllegalArgumentException(
                        String.format("the value of the serial %d is not between 0 and 50", serial));
            }
        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(
                    String.format("the firt part '%s' of line '%s' is not an integer", parts[0], line));
        }
        try {
            Integer randomNumber = Integer.valueOf(parts[1]);
            if (randomNumber < 0 || randomNumber > 500) {
                throw new IllegalArgumentException(
                        String.format("the value of the random number %d is not between 0 and 500", randomNumber));
            }
        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(
                    String.format("the firt part '%s' of line '%s' is not an integer", parts[0], line));
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: the value of the random number 789 is not between 0 and 500
```

Comment: You have a point, may not be an issue for this problem but what if this code runs several times on N files, time complexity will matter